# Is there a faster way to plot big raster files

Tags: python, visualization, raster

I have 100+ DEM files (`.slp`), the single file is bigger than 50MB. Is there a faster way to plot them with short running time?
I know two methods. One is using `gdal` to turn raster to array and then plot it using basemap `contourf()` and `contour()` method, but this method is two slow to loading the visualization window. The other method is using GeoRasters' python package, but it can not provide me my options to do visualization.

Do you have good methods to do this job?

Comment: This is not a perfect solution, but you can use imshow() instead of contour() and contourf(). It's much more efficient for rasters.

Comment: @MartinValgur thanks, but imshow() still a matplotlib method, why it more efficient for rasters?